# Search byte[] for pattern C#

Tags: c#, winforms, search, arrays

`_documentContent` contains the whole document as html view source.
`patternToFind` contains text to be searched in `_documentContent`.

Code snippet below works fine if language is English.
The same code however doesn't works at all when it encounters a language like Korean.

Sample Document

#### Present Tense

The present tense is just as you have learned.  You take the dictionary form of a verb, drop the 다, add the appropriate ending.

먹다 - 먹 + 어요 = 먹어요 
마시다 - 마시 + 어요 - 마시어요 - 마셔요.

This tense is used to represent what happens in the present.  I eat. I drink.  It is a general term for the present.

When I am trying to find 먹 the code belows fails.

can someone please suggest some solution to this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace MultiByteStringHandling
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string _documentContent = @"먹다 - 먹 + 어요 = 먹어요";
            byte[] patternToFind = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("먹");
            byte[] DocumentBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_documentContent);

            int intByteOffset = indexOf(DocumentBytes, patternToFind);
            Console.WriteLine(intByteOffset.ToString());
        }
        public int indexOf(byte[] data, byte[] pattern)
        {
            int[] failure = computeFailure(pattern);

            int j = 0;
            if (data.Length == 0) return 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
            {
                while (j > 0 && pattern[j] != data[i])
                {
                    j = failure[j - 1];
                }
                if (pattern[j] == data[i])
                {
                    j++;
                }
                if (j == pattern.Length)
                {
                    return i - pattern.Length + 1;
                }
            }
            return -1;
        }
        /**
         * Computes the failure function using a boot-strapping process,
         * where the pattern is matched against itself.
         */
        private int[] computeFailure(byte[] pattern)
        {
            int[] failure = new int[pattern.Length];

            int j = 0;
            for (int i = 1; i < pattern.Length; i++)
            {
                while (j > 0 && pattern[j] != pattern[i])
                {
                    j = failure[j - 1];
                }
                if (pattern[j] == pattern[i])
                {
                    j++;
                }
                failure[i] = j;
            }

            return failure;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please update the code with a sample document / pattern which fails. I'll edit to remove references to WinForms from the question, as it clearly doesn't have anything to do with WinForms inherently.

Comment: Are you able to see the byte[] pattern in the byte[] data manually when you are processing something with Korean characters? Is the input file really UTF-8 or is it an ANSI code page or similar?

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you want to convert the strings to byte arrays, rather than just doing `_documentContent.IndexOf("data")`?

Comment: I am having a Korean document and I need to search Korean Text within the document. The Document does contain certain portions in English. That's why I am trying to do this using byte arrays.

Comment: The Input file is a html document. I will place the snippet of that document in a moment

Comment: Strings in .NET are unicode in memory, so it should be able to search for korean text just fine. Did you try using .IndexOf?

Answer (score 6):

Seriously, why not just do the following?

```
var indexFound = documentContent.IndexOf("data");
```

Converting strings into byte arrays and then searching those doesn't make much sense to me when you're original data is text. You can always find the byte position after if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

[UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) is a variable multi-byte format. Searching for English text in Korean data will never match on a direct pattern match.  If you are scanning text you would be much better off using .IndexOf(pattern) [as [Noldorin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714650/search-byte-for-pattern-c/1714692#1714692) pointed out] or .Contains(pattern).